# Files stopped writing to BLOB store

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, rbs

I configured RBS for SharePoint 2013, and it was functioning as expected. After changing the minimum file size, files stopped writing to the blob store. Logs on both the WFE, and SQL have been checked, and no errors have been reported.

this is the command I used for changing the minimum file size.

```
$database = Get-SPContentDatabase WSS_Content
$database.RemoteBlobStorageSettings.MinimumBlobStorageSize=1048576
$database.Update()
```